# What are elegant ways to pair characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

For example, if the initial string `s` is `"0123456789"`, desired output would be an array `["01", "23", "45", "67", "89"]`.

Looking for elegant solutions in JavaScript.

What I was thinking (very non-elegantly) is to iterate through the string by splitting on the empty string and using the Array.forEach method, and insert a delimeter after every two characters, then split by that delimeter. This is *not* a good solution, but it's my starting point.

*Edit: A RegExp solution has been posted. I'd love to see if there are any other approaches.*

Comment: Uh would the downvoters care to explain why?

Comment: While it's not a bad question, asking for code that accomplishes a task without demonstrating that you have tried *something* which you're either having problems with or which you think could be solved more elegantly is generally frowned upon, as it reeks of give-me-teh-codez questions. You should be able to come up with *something* on your own, even if it's a kludgy loop with tons of superfluous counters and `.substr`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback deceze. I know this sounds like a homework help question, but I was just reading about string manipulation and this problem popped into my head. I'll update the question with some of my initial ideas.

Comment: Added a non-regex answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var array = ("0123456789").match(/\w{1,2}/g);
```

Here we use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on your string to match any two or single (`{1,2}`) word characters (`\w`) and return an array of the results.

---

Regarding your edit for a non-regex solution; you could do a far less elegant function like this:

```
String.prototype.getPairs = function()
{
    var pairs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 2)
    {
        pairs[pairs.length] = this.substr(i, 2);
    }

    return pairs;
}

var array = ("01234567890").getPairs();
```

Comment: can u explain it in details

Comment: It's a regular expression. \w matches digits, words, characters, whitespace - {2} tells it to repeat this search twice - /g is a global flag telling it to create an array of all matching results from the search

Comment: Thanks Marty, this is a really nice solution. One caveat is that for odd length strings the last character is lost. This was definitely not stated upfront as a requirement but it's something to keep in mind. For example: `"012345678".match(/\w{2}/g); // ["01", "23", "45", "67"]`

Comment: I'll update my answer to include compatibility for a left over character.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use split (and why not), you could do the following:

```
s.split(/([^][^])/).filter(function(x){return x})
```

Which splits using two consecutive characters as a *delimiter* (but because they're in a capture group, they're also part of split's result. Filtering that with the identity function serves to eliminate the empty strings (between the "delimiters"). Note that in the case of an odd number of characters, the last character will be output as a split, not a delimiter, but it doesn't matter since it will still test truthy.

(`[^]` is how you spell `.` in javascript if you really want to match any character. I had to look that up.)